# Excel-Splitting Names and Words

Tags: excel

The question is: I would like to separate all the names and roles in the text into separate columns:
i.e ( Janu Dowe (Lead AM); Ron Peno (Backup AT); Alex Nano (Backup AT)).

I want it separated "Janu Dowe" one column, Role: "Lead AM" etc.
There are 3 sometimes 4 names and roles in one cell and I want it separated all in separate columns.
I tried several ways.
Thank you

Comment: I tried this method to extract the middle name, but then it showed result with part of the other name =MID(P3,FIND("(",P3)+1,LEN(P3))

Answer (score 1):

If your data is truly how you represent it

> Name (Role);Name (role);Name(role)

Where Name can be one or more words; role is always enclosed in parentheses, and the name (role) groups are separated by semicolons, then the following macro should do the job.

The macro assumes your data is in Column A, starting in A1, and that there is nothing of value in the adjacent columns.  You will need to change the code if that is not the case.

To enter this Macro (Sub), alt-F11 opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this Macro (Sub), alt-F8 opens the macro dialog box. Select the macro by name, and RUN.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitData()
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Set r = Range("P36", Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
For Each c In r
c.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, semicolon:=True, other:=True, _
    otherchar:="("
Next c

Set r = r.CurrentRegion
r.Replace what:=")", replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart
r.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

This could be done manually, but a macro might be simpler.  The macro first executes the TextToColumns method, using semicolon and "(" as delimiters; then it used the Replace method to remove the residual ")"

Comment: I edited the Set r=Range ("p36", Cells (Rows.Count, "P").End(x1Up) since my data starts from P36. However, i need both names first & last together be separated from the other 3 set of names and roles. If we can adjust the macro for that would be great, but i m not sure. Thank you.

Comment: That should be what happens.  I will post a picture

Comment: Unable to post a picture with Edit so added a second answer after editing the first answer to show the change in Set r =

Answer (score 0):

If column 1 is

Alex isa Nano (Backup AT); Ron Peno (Backup AT); Janu Dowe Smyth (Lead AM)

Then parsing is as follows
    =LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-2)
    =MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,(FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1))-1)
    =MID(A1,FIND(";",A1)+2,FIND("(",A1,FIND(";",A1))-FIND(";",A1)-2)
    =MID(A1,FIND("(",A1,FIND(";",A1))+1,FIND(")",A1,FIND(";",A1))-FIND("(",A1,FIND(";",A1))-1)
    =MID(A1,FIND(")",A1,FIND(";",A1))+3,FIND("(",A1,FIND(";",A1,FIND(";",A1)+1))-FIND(";",A1,FIND(";",A1)+1)-2)
    =MID(A1,FIND("(",A1,FIND(";",A1,FIND(";",A1)+1))+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("(",A1,FIND(";",A1,FIND(";",A1)+1))-1)

Comment: The second column displays the characters of the first column up until it finds a left parens.  The third column calculates the the length between the left and right parens and displays that number of characters starting with the character to the right of the opening parens.

Comment: thanx for u replay. Also, I need to have "Ron Peno" & Backup At and "Alex Nano" & "Backup AT" all in separate columns. All of the names and roles are in once cell, is the challenge.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part.  so your cell is "Janu Dowe (Lead AM); Ron Peno (Backup AT); Alex Nano (Backup AT)"  With semicolons as separaters?

Comment: Correct! All names and roles need be in separate columns.

Comment: Val! I added the entire formula in one cell and it's giving me a #VALUE! error. Not sure if any of the formula you edited has to be split somewhere but when i entered the entire formula in one cell it give me the #value error.

Comment: It seems that this formula only works for three pairs; if there is a fourth or more, it will concatenated with the last.  In addition, it puts the different items into the same column; different rows.  I thought he wanted the results in different columns.  You also need to watch the formatting.  I don't think the Enter Code symbol works as expected yet.

Comment: question is same because the result was not what i wanted. It's quite challenging to segragate one person by first & last name. Then by role. The challenge is that you have 4,5 people in one cell to be segragated. The text-to-column fiture works. However, when spliting the person's both names from the role doesn't work. Thanx for the efforts...

Comment: You still have not commented on the problem with the solution I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Before Data showing how it is entered on the worksheet in cells P36:P37

[image: Data as Entered Originally]

After Macro, showing the results in P36:U37; split into cells

If this is not what you want, you will need to be more descriptive

[image: Data after macro is run]